# Sending data from C/C++ to MaxScript

Tags: maxscript

I want to use the data coming from the multiple sensors coming through the serial port to rotate a box in 3DS Max . The data is first filtered using the KAlman filter and is set in the proper form but i dont know how can i use the reformed data in the Max Script to do the rotation . I know the max script to rotate but i dont know how do i send the data from somewhere else to MaxScript . Please help me out

Comment: Don't send data from C++ to maxscript. Just use the C++ API to do the rotations.

Comment: Would it help to send MaxScript commands by network?  It is possible to start a web server *inside of 3ds max* and accept TCP/UDP connections from clients, then receive commands line by line, and execute them in MaxScript engine. Also possible to send the output back to the client. I have a working prototype here: https://github.com/nmalex/remote-maxscript.dlx

Answer (score 1):

With maxscript you can use .net,
using the c++ SDK for this simple job is much more work then simply using .net combined with maxscript.

I would use that example below and read it back instead of writing.
The example can be found here

http://forums.cgsociety.org/showthread.php?t=898081